# Possible to make tabs in TabPane different width from eachother?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to make different width between my tabs in a TabPane, but I can't figure out how to? I want the tabs in chunks of 3 or so, is that possible?

Cheers!

Comment: I searched Google for **"Java Swing TabPane Tab Width"** and the second link gave me: [Change the Tab Size of JTabbedPane](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/xuanyun/archive/2009/01/change_the_tab.html)

Comment: I use JavaFX, and I'm not talking about the width of the tabs, I'm talking about the width of the spaces between the tabs.

Comment: I searched Google again for **"Javafx TabPane space between tabs"**, and this time the first link gave me: [How to increase the gap between two tabs?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2370942?tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonny Henly's comment, I was able to come up with this. I think it does what you were describing.

You can set the style for `Tab`s individually, so you can cycle through all of the Tabs attached to the `TabPane` and set special styling on every nth tab.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabGroups extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tab1.setContent(new Rectangle(200.0d, 200.0d, Color.LIGHTGREEN));
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        tab2.setContent(new Rectangle(200.0d, 200.0d, Color.LIGHTSTEELBLUE));
        Tab tab3 = new Tab("Tab 3");
        tab3.setContent(new Rectangle(200.0d, 200.0d, Color.LIGHTCORAL));

        Tab tabA = new Tab("Tab A");
        tabA.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
        tabA.setContent(new Circle(100.0d, 100.0d, 100.0d, Color.BLUE));
        Tab tabB = new Tab("Tab B");
        tabB.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
        tabB.setContent(new Circle(100.0d, 100.0d, 100.0d, Color.GREEN));
        Tab tabC = new Tab("Tab C");
        tabC.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
        tabC.setContent(new Circle(100.0d, 100.0d, 100.0d, Color.YELLOW));

        Tab tabX = new Tab("Tab X");
        tabX.setContent(new TextField("This is " + tabX.getText()));
        Tab tabY = new Tab("Tab Y");
        tabY.setContent(new TextField("This is " + tabY.getText()));

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2, tab3, tabA, tabB, tabC, tabX, tabY);
        ObservableList<Tab> theTabs = tabPane.getTabs();

        // Add special CSS to every third tab.
        String addedStyle = "-fx-background-insets: 0 5em 0 0, 1 5em 1 1, 2 5em 0 0;"
                        + "-fx-padding: 0.083333em 5em 0.083333em 0.5em;";
        int counter = 1;
        for (Tab t : theTabs) {
            if ((counter % 3) == 0) {
                String existingStyle = t.getStyle();
                String newStyle;
                if (existingStyle != null) {
                    newStyle = existingStyle + addedStyle;
                } else {
                    newStyle = addedStyle;
                }
                t.styleProperty().setValue(newStyle);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        tabPane.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(tabPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Using the `setStyle()` method will completely replace any styling that existed on the tab, so, depending on what the theme for the program does, you probably want to grab the existing style and append any changes to the end. (The last setting of the property overrides anything earlier. For example, a style might set the background to black early in the list of properties, but changing it to white later in the list will override the earlier setting.) Also, I am no CSS expert and the style used below is problematic in that the right and bottom edge of every third tab is messed up. Also, the spacing between the second and third tabs is messed up.

Hope that helps.